# Time returns wrong value if timezone incorrect

Tags: android, time, calendar

If device has incorrect timezone Time will return incorrect value, while Calendar will work. My app was built using Time, and I would like to keep it, but I need to fix the timezone issue.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
String out= c.get(Calendar.HOUR)+":"+c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
Toast.makeText(this,  ""+out, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//returns correct time

Time currentTime = new Time();
currentTime.setToNow();
Toast.makeText(this,  currentTime.format("%H:%M"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//returns incorrect time
```

Comment: Isn't this just GIGO?

Comment: What is the incorrect value?

Comment: 1 hour 20 minutes off (instead of 1.42 it's 00:12)

Comment: I tested on my machine, it is correct. Have you tested it on emulator?

Comment: Maybe I should have added, problem occurs mostly on BlackBerry 10 devices (ported), but it also happens on my Galaxy S (ICS).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but I have a very localized app so I just force the timezone from a res/strings.xml variable.

Something like this:

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(); 

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(context.getString(R.string.app_timezone)));

Toast.makeText(this, dateFormat.format(input.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Then in res/strings.xml

```
<string name="app_timezone">GMT+8:00</string>
```

Comment: I can get it to work using Calendar and SimpleDateFormat, but That would require for me to fix the whole app and will result in higher battery consumption.

Comment: I'm curious how it would increase battery consumption but that aside.  I find that moving all of this kind of logic into a utility class allows me to do then make bulk changes quite easily.  If you are stuck with Time you could always make the util take Time and use Calendar internally.  e.g. DateUtils.format(new Time())